# Use a parameter on server side that was sent by post request

Tags: node.js, angular

I am pretty new on Node.js and faced with a problem, where I want to send an email by post request and use it on my server side. 
Does somebody know how I should use it?
Regards.

My code :

Client-side

this is app.component.html

```
  <a class="nav-link" style="cursor:pointer" *ngIf="_authService.loggedIn()" 
 (click)="_authService.logoutUser()" >Logout</a>
```

auth.service.ts

```
logoutUser() 
{
this.userEmail = localStorage.getItem('email')
localStorage.removeItem('token')
localStorage.removeItem('email')
this._router.navigate(['/login'])        
this.logUser(this.userEmail).subscribe(
  res => this.menu = res,
  err => console.log(err)
)
  }
logUser(userEmail:any)
{
  return this.http.post<any>(this._logOut,userEmail)
}
```

Server side :

api.js

```
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
userData = req.body
console.log(userData)
 })
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an object in the body:

```
logUser(userEmail:any)
{
  return this.http.post<any>(this._logOut,{userEmail: userEmail})
}
```